# GeoPackage in QGIS: what are .gpkg-shm and .gpkg-wal files?

Tags: qgis, geopackage

In QGIS, if I open some GeoPackage file like `mylayers.gpkg`, it will create two files named `mylayers.gpkg-shm` and `mylayers.gpkg-wal` in the same folder. After I close QGIS, these files disappear. I understand that they are temporary files, but I wonder what their purpose is.

Comment: not sure but something related with write protection in case of concurrent/simultaneous file access ...

Comment: `wal` is the write ahead log, no idea what `shm` is though

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As the *SQLite* core of a *GeoPackage* is a single-file based RDB, it needs to utilize [temporary support structures](https://sqlite.org/tempfiles.html) to guarantee [atomic transaction management](https://sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html).

*SQLite* supports different mechanics to achieve this, and the *QGIS* specific *GPKG* implementation defaults to *[**W**rite **A**head **L**ogging (WAL)](https://sqlite.org/wal.html)*, available in *SQLite* > 3.7, where

- the `*.gpkg-wal` file holds the *WAL* for the current connection; this file keeps a progressive data log of the transactional state of the DB between `COMMIT`s (or `ROLLBACK`s)
- the `*.gpkg-shm` **SH**hared **M**emory file manages concurrent access to the DB via an index to the *WAL*

Comment: The "GPKG implementation"  above refers specifically to QGIS GPKG implementation. It sets the GeoPackage databases into WAL mode, if they are not already, with  pragma command `PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;` https://sqlite.org/wal.html#activating_and_configuring_wal_mode. What users should know is not to send .gpkg files to other users before the .wal and .shm files have disappeared.

Comment: @user30184 amended.

Comment: Does it mean that two or more desktop users can simultaneously edit _the same_ GeoPackage file - stored, for example, on a shared network disk - without corrupting data?

Comment: @Yaroslav Yes, *SQLite* is ACID compliant and concurrency save for *readers*, but supports only a single *writer* process at a time; if a transaction is open running `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or *DDL* statements, other transactions have to wait until the current transaction was committed/rollback-ed. In practice, though, in a *QGIS* edit session, the lock happens at save time, so you won't feel much of this limitation.